# Encounter assertionError: Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely with Beam/Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to use apache beam and dataflow to speed up some data processing, but it encounters:

`'Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely.') AssertionError: Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely.`

I have simplified my pipeline for testing, but still getting the error(**although I could run successfully locally use DirectRunner**, so I figure it should be some naive setup issue or a bug in beam/dataflow? Also, I looked up and there is another issue would give similar error that is caused by reading large amount of data from google storage, which is likely already fixed. I don't think my case relates to that as my minimal code does not past test. Below are my minimal code (long argparse code are kept as I suspect error might relate to them?):

```
import os
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
import logging

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True) -> None:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--given_landmarks', default=False, type=bool,
                        help="Whether to use pre-selected landmark objects")
    parser.add_argument('--hmm_type', default='path_specific', type=str, choices=['path_specific', 'hard_em',  'random'],
                        help='The HMM type. Currently Path-specific, Hard EM, and Random are available.')
    parser.add_argument('--magnitude_normalization', default='normal', type=str,choices=['gamma', 'normal'],
                        help="Distribution type for calculating probability of magnitude for Observer.")
    parser.add_argument('--instruction_type', default='full', type=str,
                        choices=['full', 'object_only', 'direction_only',
                                'mask_object', 'mask_direction'],
                        help='Toggle for full/object-only/direction-only instructions.')
    parser.add_argument('--num_instructions', default=1, type=int,
                        help="The number of instructions to generate per path")
    parser.add_argument('--mp3d_dir', default='/path/to/matterport_data/', type=str,
                        help='Path to Room-to-Room scan data.')
    parser.add_argument('--path_input_dir', default=None, type=str,
                        help='Path to Room-to-Room JSON data.')

    parser.add_argument('--dataset', default=None, type=str, choices=[
                        'R2R', 'R4R', 'RxR'], help='Data source.')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--file_identifier', default='val_seen', type=str,
        help='Source JSON file identifier for Crafty instruction creation.')

    parser.add_argument('--output_file', default=None, type=str,
                    help='Output file to save generated instructions.')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--appraiser_file', type=str,
        default='./crafty.object_idfs.r2r_train.txt',
        help='File to read appraiser information from.')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--full_train_file_path', default=None, type=str,
        help='Path to full training file, for EM training covering all partitions.')

    args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    print(args)
    if not os.path.exists(args.output_file):
        os.makedirs(args.output_file)

    def pipeline(root):

        logging.info('Starting Beam pipeline.')
        outputs = (
        root
        | 'create_input_1' >> beam.Create([1,2,3,4,5])
        | 'map' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
        )
        outputs | beam.Map(print)

    pipeline_options = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    # pipeline_options = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions()
    # pipeline_options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    # pipeline_options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.DirectOptions
      # ).direct_num_workers = os.cpu_count()
    #pipeline_options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.DirectOptions).direct_running_mode = "multi-processing"

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as root:
        pipeline(root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

And my command follows from [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python):

```
 python test.py  \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    --path_input_dir gs://somepath \
    --dataset somename  \
    --mp3d_dir gs://somepath  \
    --file_identifier someid  \
    --output_file gs://some/other/path  \
    --num_instructions 1 \
    --region us-east1 \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project someproject-id \
    --temp_location gs://someloc
```

Thanks for any comments or suggestions!

Comment: This could be a bug. I suggest you catch the `AssertionError` and check what state the job is in. It would also be great to propose a pull request to Beam to provide a more actionable error message that indicates what the job state is.

Comment: This error occurs [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/35881d7553335a6c11119b3ad799529d56b51fbe/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py#L1621) in the Beam codebase. You can see that it means the thread waiting for the job to finish died. It may have been killed for another reason. Can you find any error or reason the thread terminated?

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104176/google-cloud-dataflow-python-sdk-updates which links to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5529. So then we should ask: what version of Beam are you using?

Comment: @KennKnowles Thanks for your comment, I am using 2.30.0; And could you elaborate on how to catch `AssertionError` ? Do I do this in GCP?

Comment: I was thinking

```
try:
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as root:
        pipeline(root)
except AssertionError:
   # something something
```

Comment: I can see how the `with` statement obscures this ability. If you create the pipeline without a `with` statement and then call `root.run(...)` you can retrieve a Job object and inspect the status.

Comment: @KennKnowles , I was trying to: `try: root = beam.Pipeline(...) pipeline(root) except AssertionError: ...`, but this way, I think the pipeline didn't run at all. You mention `root.run(...)`, I look it up in source code, but not clear how to use it... Every example I saw in official doc use `with ...pipeline as p ....` Could you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: You can use the pipeline as a context manager with the `with` clause. You can also use the pipeline `root=beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)` as a builder to append transforms into it. Then explicitly call `result = root.run()`. Then `try: result.wait_until_finish() except AssertionError: #result.wait_until_finish() or other retry logic`. The logic polling for job completion is [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/35881d7553335a6c11119b3ad799529d56b51fbe/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py#L148)

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect answer, but this error message indicates that the thread watching and waiting for your job to finish was terminated even though the job was not completed, even though you did not specify a maximum time to wait. It could have died for a variety of reasons.

The error occurs [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/35881d7553335a6c11119b3ad799529d56b51fbe/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py#L1621) in the Beam codebase, for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the logs? It may be a permissions issue. I received the same error, and in the job logs I had this message:

> Workflow failed. Causes: Permissions verification for controller
> service account failed. All permissions in IAM role
> roles/dataflow.worker should be granted to controller service account
> XXXXXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32223894)